# File of route paths in Angular routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx-router-store

I am currently working on creating routes for my Angular project,
and I am interested whether it is a practice in Angular world, to have a list of paths, in the same manner as you have enums of actions in ngrx, so they can be used in multiple places?

Something in the manner of

```
export enum StuffActionTypes {
  StuffRequested = '[StuffIndexPage] Stuff Requested',
  StuffLoaded = '[StuffAPI] Stuff Loaded',
}
```

just for the paths

Answer (score 0):

Routes are an array of objects and you can put it in a separete file just with the right imports and exports, even you can create routes for each module if requiered. I've saw a few ways of implementing it, the base one is:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './info/info.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

the example before is from angular.io documentation. You can do many complex things with the router, there are good courses on pluralsight